# Creating an in page poll with a % value total

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to this site and I am looking for a little guidance. I want to create a poll for my website, several actually where people pick 1-5 and t outputs the total as a percentage value but I am not sure what programming language would be best to start with? any guidance would be amazing.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-) I gues your question (_"which programming language?"_) is too broad ...

Comment: Apologies, I thought it might be but I am a little lost as to the best way to ask the question. I have found multiple poll generators online but none really cover what I want to achieve.

Comment: @EvanSorrell, you could try the [Software Engineer](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour) website, that is from this community, but I'm not sure that something so broad will get the answer you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to save the data, you will need some kind of database. For the frontend, your tags suggest that you know what to use: HTML/CSS/JS will suite you just fine.

Now for the backend (the server side which stores the data and hands it to your frontend): For beginners, I'd suggest PHP. You can also use this for the frontend to display the results based on a flag you set. Regarding the database, use MySQL.

Take this approach:

```
index.php -> loads survey
index.php?type=results -> loads results
index.php?type=submit -> submits data to the database
```

This is the most simple structure you can achieve for what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, Is it possible to load the results alongside the poll before voting? as each poll will be a value of 1 to 5 I would like to display the average rating before a user has voted.

Comment: Sure, you can easily show the progress before voting. Just adapt the main page for this.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help, I now have a direction to head.

Comment: No problem! Don't hesitate to contact me in this post should you need any help.